# Jquery action event after DOM creation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button being created after the DOM is created. That button has an action. What I'm having trouble is binding that action to the button. I have researched and people said to us the .on() function but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/e7a4X/

HTML

```
<button id="firstClick">Click me to create another button</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#firstClick').click(function() {
    $('#container').append('<button class="second-button">Button after DOM</button>');
});

$('.second-button').on('click', function () {
    alert("Success");
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working demoL http://jsfiddle.net/Metsx/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ZB2Ns/

- API : `.on` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Now to make your event know about the click event you need `.on` at `document` or at `#container` level, which  attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object.

Rest should fit your need `:)`

**Code**

```
$('#firstClick').click(function() {
    $('#container').append('<button class="second-button">Button after DOM</button>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.second-button', function () {
    alert("Success");
})
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. I really appreciate the two different examples.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to tell the DOM, parent to listen to its child.

The issue is that Your new .second-button is a new element, and you have defined your .click function before the DOM actually exists.

But all DOM interactions will trigger a event propagations(bubbling), therefore you can tell #container to listen for click events coming from .second-button

Or use $(document).on to listen, since the bubbling will go all the way to the document root.

If you are a performance minimalist than you would just do #container .on, and stop the propagation from that point, since theres no need to travel to every parent node, but you might eventually need to listen it from the parent of the #container, who knows

Comment: Really insightful on how this function works. I actually had a much more deeper DOM element appending and @Tats_innit's solution wasn't working for a minute. With your explanation I was able to tell the element that's already in the DOM to listen to the click event and move down the element to trigger the specific element. I fully undestand it now. Thank you.